# Bytestream upload of content-type: application/pgp-signature differs after updating resteasy

Tags: jboss, wildfly, multipartform-data, resteasy

I have a rest facade which is defined the following way using rest-easy:

```java
    @POST
    @Path("/xxx")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    @RolesAllowed(XXX)
    @Operation(summary = "XXX")
    @APIResponse(responseCode = HttpStatus.HTTP_OK, description = "XXX",
            content = @Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = EmptyResponse.class)))
    @APIResponse(responseCode = HttpStatus.HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED, description = DefaultApiResponseMessages.UNAUTHORIZED)
    @APIResponse(responseCode = HttpStatus.HTTP_FORBIDDEN, description = DefaultApiResponseMessages.FORBIDDEN)
    @APIResponse(responseCode = HttpStatus.HTTP_INTERNAL_ERROR, description = DefaultApiResponseMessages.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    public Response putXXX(
            @Parameter(description = "XXX", required = true)
                    MultipartFormDataInput input) {
```

We used jboss wildfly 20 before with resteasy-multipart-provider in version 2.2.3.GA. After upgrading to jboss Wildfly 27 and therefore upgrading to jakarta we're now using resteasy-multipart-provider in version 6.2.2.Final.

One of the input-parts uploaded by the users is a pgp-signature file. When inspecting the bytestream of the body of the pgp-signature file we get differing bytestreams for one and the same pgp-signature file we are uploading. This causes our application to break after the update.
The content type is of the file both times is recognised correctly with:
Content-Type: application/pgp-signature

Can somebody help me?

I already tried writing an interceptor for the following InputPart variables and added the interceptor to the web.xml

```java
    String DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE_PROPERTY = "resteasy.provider.multipart.inputpart.defaultContentType";
    String DEFAULT_CHARSET_PROPERTY = "resteasy.provider.multipart.inputpart.defaultCharset";
```

It did indeed change/add charset/content-type properties when debugging the MultipartFormDataInput, but it had no effect on the inputpart bodies bytestream.

Comment: What version of RESTEasy are you compiling against? `MultipartFormDataIntput` was removed long ago. It's not even in WildFly 20 which uses RESTEasy 3.12.x.

Comment: Hello @JamesR.Perkins,  we're using WildFly 27 which provides version 6.2.1.Final. MultipartFormDataInput can be found under org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.multipart

Comment: My apologies, I must have been looking for the wrong type. I can clearly see it now. I'll have to see if I can come up with a reproducer for this.

Comment: Thanks in advance. We are still investigating here and are looking forward to solve this issue